# Call a method in Playwright only when test title contains certain @tag

Tags: typescript, azure-devops, playwright

I have recently started my journey with Playwright with TS after many years of writing tests in Selenium, including SpecFlow, NUnit and others.

What I want to reach is to perform an action (in my case calling AzureDevOps API to mark test as automated - Associated Automation) only for the tests containing certain `@tag` in the test title (e.g. @123456).

```
    test('shows error on invalid login details, @loginerror @123456', async () => {
    await loginPage.login(loginDetails_workingUsers[0].username, 'invalidPwd')
    await expect(loginPage.usernameInput).toHaveAttribute('class', /error$/)
    await expect(loginPage.passwordInput).toHaveAttribute('class', /error$/);
    await expect(loginPage.errorMsg).toHaveText('Epic sadface: Username and password do not match any user in this service')
})
```

In other words, I want to call an API each time there is certain @tag in a test title and have this logic in one place only, not in each test method.

In SpecFlow, I was simply accessing `ScenarioContext` in `[AfterScenario/BeforeScenario]`, in other framework I've been using custom attribute `[AssociatedAutomation(123456)]`

In playwright all I see is an access to the test title via `testInfo` in a test method.

Perfect solution would be to access `testInfo` in a `test.beforeEach` but outside the test classes.

Appreciate the support!

I already tried to access `testInfo.title` in a test method or in `test.beforeEach` in a test class but it's not what I want to have.

Comment: Please share your current code snippet and related code where you are accessing testInfo.title so that someone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

In general ,this is how you can get the tag info from test title:

```
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';

test('basic test @myTag', async ({ page }, testInfo) => {
  expect(testInfo.title).toContain('@myTag');
 
});
```

Comment: this is what I know. My question is how to access testInfo.title in general beforeEach or a test fixture. You dropped me a snippet how to use it inside a test method.

Comment: Please share your code first so that all can know  what you have tried so far and can actually help you otherwise it's all talk.

Comment: Show us the code along with errors you are getting.

Comment: My code doesn't differ much from your code, question is clear and simple, let me rephrase it:
How to read test title outside of the test method and test class?